# Why is my data reader only returning one row?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using `SqlDataReader` to show data in a `RichTextBox`, but I only get one row.

**This is my code:**

```
  Dim strsql As String
        Dim OrdenNumero As Integer
        Dim Articulo As String
        Dim con As New SqlConnection("")

        strsql = "SELECT * FROM OrdenesParaMonitor WHERE Orden# = (SELECT MAX(Orden#) from OrdenesParaMonitor);"

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strsql, con)

        Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
        con.Open()
        myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If myreader.HasRows = True Then
            While myreader.Read()
                OrdenNumero = myreader("Orden#")
                Articulo = myreader("Articulo")
                Label1.Text = OrdenNumero
                RichTextBox1.Text = Articulo


            End While
        End If
     End Sub
```

I know I have to loop if I want to read all the rows, but no one uses VB.NET so its hard to find a good example on how to do this as a beginner.

Comment: How many rows does that exact query return when run in SSMS? Its looks to me like you are selecting only the most recent order?

Comment: No, probably your query returns all the records it finds. The problem is in the setting of the text to the controls inside the loop. You don't append the new text to the previous text, you replace at each loop what you have set in the previous loop. The code ends showing just the data from the last record

Comment: @DaleK It depends on the number of items in the order. So lets say there are beans and a cookie in a order. The query will return two rows, '2606 beans' and '2606 Cookie'

Comment: @Steve you are right I think that is it. would you mind giving me an example with code? I will accept your answer.

Comment: `RichTextBox1.Text += Articulo`? How do you want to display the multiple rows? You need to ensure you are adding the new row data to your existing data, rather than overwriting it.

Comment: Side point: you should put your connection, command and reader objects in `Using` blocks. Also your SQL is probably more efficient as `SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES * FROM OrdenesParaMonitor ORDER BY Order# DESC;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have told in my comment, the problem is how the code sets the text for the two controls. Setting the text without appending to the previous one, just replaces the current text with the data coming from the record and leaves just the last set.

Instead you should append to the current text. This could be done with `&=` operator for the label or using the specific `AppendText` method for the `RichTextBox`.

```
While myreader.Read()
    OrdenNumero = myreader("Orden#")
    Articulo = myreader("Articulo")
    Label1.Text &= OrdenNumero   ' Append to the previous text
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(Articulo)
    ' or add a newline at each step
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(Articulo & Environment.NewLine)

End While
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why is my data reader only returning one row?

It may not be, but you're overwriting the same set of variables and UI elements for each row.  So you may only be *seeing* the last row after the While loop.

Debug your project and put a breakpoint inside the while loop to be sure.

> no one uses VB.NET so its hard to find a good example on how to do this as a beginner.

Have you considered that C# might be a better language for you to learn, since there are so many more examples.  VB.NET is mostly used by people with lots of experience programming in VB.NET and/or VBA.

Comment: I am being forced to use VB.NET for my work. But once I finish this project I will switch to C# 100%.